# Problem with `truffle init`

Tags: blockchain, truffle, nodejs

I can't start truffle, this is the Error:

```
truffle init

/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/node_modules/ether-pudding/index.js:182
      for (var file of files) {
                   ^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
    at Module._compile (module.js:439:25)
    at Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .js] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/node_modules/babel-register/lib/node.js:152:7)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/lib/profiler.js:7:15)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .js] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/node_modules/babel-register/lib/node.js:152:7)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/lib/compiler.js:11:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .js] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/node_modules/babel-register/lib/node.js:152:7)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
```

Any idea what the problem might be?

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem. You should have a NodeJS version of 5.x or higher.